# ios - ECSlidingViewController "reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]"

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm using the following pages

-MenuViewController
-ViewController(Main)
-ListViewController

`ECSlidingViewController` created using the menu. `ViewController` (main) menu on page directly open, but when I try to open a subpage menu with the following line of `listviewcontroller` get the error:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

I received the error are as follows:

> -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NSArray` method `insertObject:atIndex` does not accept `nil`. If you do want to insert a `nil` object into an array, or rather, a representation of a `nil` entry, use `[NSNull null]`, so you have:

```
[myArray insertObject[NSNull null] atIndex:myIndex]
```

In your case, however, probably the root cause of the error is that `self.slidingViewController.panGesture` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue too. I issue was that when I added the ECSlidingViewController. I still had one of my functions connecting to the topviewcontroller

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController: topViewController];
```

When I needed to make sure it was connected to the initial view controller for the ECSlidingViewController.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController: initialEXViewController];
```